# Prudent vs. prudential

Tags: vocabulary

Page 744 of Garner's fourth reads

> **Prudent** = exhibiting prudence <*the detective’s prudent withholding of judgment on the killing proved brilliant in the end*>.
>
> **Prudential** = relating to, considered from the point of view of, or dictated by prudence <*the senator opposed the policy on both moral
> and prudential grounds*>.

However I still cannot see any clear difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

Prudential is more often used to refer to what people do rather than people themselves: *"A person is prudent if he has prudential motives."*

> These words are derived from a Latin term meaning "to look after," "to provide for." Prudent is employed to mean "wise," "cautious," "practical," "careful in providing for one's interests," "sensible about planning for the future": "It is always prudent to plan a trip carefully." "A prudent man will try to save money for family emergencies."

> Prudential is used to refer not to acts themselves or to persons performing acts but to considerations or motives leading to action."A prudent person takes care of his health; prudential considerations often cause persons to watch out for their health."

(problem_words.enacademic.com)

Comment: “To call an act prudent,” wrote
H.W. Fowler, “is normally to commend it; to call it
-ial is more often than not to disparage it” (FMEU1
at 473)